# Google Chrome V102.0.5005.63 Timeout Exception Error

Tags: google-chrome

We are seeing an issue with our pre-production and production native homegrown web app where after 15-30 seconds it appears that the session times out when making the preflight API call in the Chrome browser. Edge v101.0.1210.53 appears to be working.  We don't see any other errors in the Chrome inspect console.

We saw this behavior on May 25, 2022 right around when chrome 102 got pushed to the browsers. IF we use inspect and turn off the cache then we still see issues with loading the app.

Testing using chrome 101.0.4951.61 against the same web app on my virtual machine does not reproduce the issue.  After the browser updated on the virtual machine, the error was reproduced.

Are there any new features in 102 we could turn off to see if a specific new security check might be at play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears to be a bug in chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1329248

Work around is to disable this: chrome://flags/#private-network-access-send-preflights